# Controlling row heights precisely in an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

For an HTML table, I've found that if I set

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 0;
}
```

I can then specify the widths of each column in the `col` elements, and they will be respected, i.e. cells can't increase the width of a column, instead they have to deal with overflow.

Is there any way to do the same for row height? What I want to do is be able to specify the row height in each `tr` element, and then individual cells can't make it any taller, they just have to deal with vertical overflow if their content wants to be larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `line-height:nPX` to each td. In my example i truncat long text for better readability.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 200px; 
}

table td {
   line-height: 12px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td> 1 Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```